# How to login into a Ubuntu machine from Windows

Tags: server, windows, remote

We have Windows Vista/XP machines connected to a Win 2k3 server in our LAN environment. We recently got few laptops configured w/Ubuntu 11 and we would like to enable our Windows users to remote login into these Ubuntu machines (e.g. with their own user id(s)) so that they can work on them.

What should I do to achieve this?

Note: We don't want to use anything like TeamViewer or VNCViewer ..., we just need terminal access to these machines so that we can compile/run programs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if your goal is to access to a remote Ubuntu machine just by terminal connection, you can use ssh. You've to install openssh-server by apt on Ubuntu and use for example Putty from windows.

Comment: No, this is a machine in our LAN and not outside our LAN. Does the same mechanism hold good. I would also like to provide different username/passwords for all these users, so that they can login into their respective accounts.

Comment: In this case, 'remote' means "one you aren't sitting in front of", even if they are on the same LAN or subnet. So yes, PuTTy would be an excellent option for terminal access from your Windows machines to the Linux machines.  Setting up that many user accounts by hand may be a little tedious, but not too hard.

Comment: I have done this (ssh) I used openssh on the windows end, but colleagues used putty. I also ran an X11 server on the windows machines for when I wanted to display a graph etc. Setting us keys instead of passwords is more secure. (these are laptops? so will go out side).

Answer (score 23):

I recommed to use **`SSH`** if you need terminal access.

1. Install `openssh-server` on Ubuntu machine.

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server

Or you can find under software center.

[image]

To connect from a Windows machine, download putty from [HERE](http://www.putty.org/). and install under windows.

Open putty and type in the Host Name or IP address for the Ubuntu machine.

[image]

Type your username and password and login

[image]

That is all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use xrdp if you want to connect with remote desktop.

Here is a simple tutorial: http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.