# How to use a PC workstation, that works with Ubuntu, as server for files and computing on this same server?

Tags: server, 18.04

I have a desktop computer, with its tower. On this one, there is Ubuntu 18.04.2.
I have a laptop too. Currently there is only Windows 7, but normally I can create a dual boot with Ubuntu.

The desktop computer has more capacity in RAM (2x more), CPU (3x more) and so on. Besides there are my databases in its storage.
The laptop is too old to make computation with the files present in the desktop computer. But this is not a trash for all that.

Let's see an example.

I want to use Anaconda/Jupyterlab on my laptop. In the same time, I want to access files (notebooks and data) present in the desktop computer. But I want to access it through my laptop, and if I want to make any computation in the notebooks, I want the desktop computer's RAM and CUP to compute. Because as I told my laptop is too old, and there is no way to improve the hardware.

Moreover, I want to add a precision. I don't know if this is necessary but we never know. I don't want to transform my desktop computer as only a server. This is a workstation, and I want it to be able to do the both: workstation when I want, server when I want.
Another precision. I have VNC (free version) on my two computers. It works well that's not the problem. But this is not very convenient. The cons is when I connect to my desktop computer through VNC on my laptop, the screen is more adapted to my the desktop computer. Besides the session is opened on the desktop computer, that's another cons.

Honestly I did some researchs, but I have not enough knowledge to know which mean is answering my needs. And I have not enough knowledge to know if it's clearly possible or not.

Comment: Since Jupyterlab is web-based, any-OS, any-browser remote control seems possible The [Jupyterlab documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/urls.html) explains how.

Comment: @user535733 ok. That's for days I am searching to make a dual boot but it failed. Well, now as you said I can use any-OS for remote control.
Must I use an SSH protocol to connect my Win7 laptop to my Ubuntu workstation? I see many topics about it, but they speak with expert terms I don't always understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access Jupyter Notebook or Lab by a client (here Windows 7 laptop) while resources are in server (here an Ubuntu PC) an SSH tunnel is needed.

From the server side we can install OpenSHH on Ubuntu as shown in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136671/how-to-login-into-a-ubuntu-machine-from-windows) with the command: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

From the client side, windows 7, we can use PuTTY. This is well described in this [DigitalOcean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-run-connect-to-jupyter-notebook-on-remote-server). But no need to use the command `source ~/environments/my_env/bin/activate` as they do.
To know Ubuntu server's IP we write the command `ip addr show` in its terminal. Look at the [tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/check-ip-address-ubuntu-18-04-desktop/) here.
Now, We can use a different port if we want for ssh tunnel settings.

For instance if we want the jupyter lab to be executed through port 9000 in the server side, we write the command: `jupyter lab --port=9000` in PuTTY prompt. We must precise in PuTTY SHH Tunnels settings `Destination: localhost:9000` where here localhost is the server... it can be confusing if we are not attentive.

Then in the browser we connect at *http://localhost:8000*, where port 8000 is the one  configured for the client side. After it, normally it opens with a page asking for the token. This token is given by the command `jupyter lab` in PuTTY's shell (which is the shell to order the server).